# Which hardware/softwares do I need in order to push new software from a single central computer (server?) to many client computers at once?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008

I apologise in advance if I use the wrong terminology, or say anything spectacularly ignorant. I'm bound to and, in fact, my problem is precisely the fact that I do not know the correct terminology in order to search for the right information on the internet!

I work at a school where we have approximately 100 windows computers. They are all individual computers that connect to a number of wireless switches which are all in turn connected to some scary looking hardware in the basement. I guess this is what would be considered a peer-to-peer arrangement. I want to implement a system with a server(s) so that users log in over the network (so I can know who was logged in when and where). I also need to be able to install software on all the computers at once (or make it so that individual users can run software over the network that's stored on the server?)

Those are the basics of what I'd like to be able to achieve, though some extra functionality would be great too. My question is: what types of software and hadware would I need in order to make something like this happen?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: That's a tall order and pack a lot of wanting into such a small question.   And the statement "connected to some scary looking hardware in teh basement" makes advising you on what you want to do a little scary.  If you can't even assess what you have, I'm afraid you will *very* quickly get in over your head.  Not intending to be insulting but I'd be irresponsible not to warn you.  Some of what you're asking for is fairly advanced.  Doing it for 100 users (and especially if you expect them to keep working while you do it) will not be trivial.  I'll try to answer some of your questions below.

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of centralized login and sharing resources (like document files & folders) you will want a server.  If you just want to share files a simple NAS appliance might do but if you want centralized logins and management of users (probably you do, as in a school students will come and go every semester) you want what's called a Domain Server.  Windows server 2012 for example is the current release.  You will need a license for the server and licenses (called CALs) for each of either the number of computers or number of users.  Using computers as example you will need 100 CALs on top of the server.  Be prepared this will not be cheap.

Now basically (and this is *highly* simplified)  you will configure the server for Active Directory (AD) and create a Domain on your AD.  You will need to join each of the 100 computer to that domain.  AD provides tools called Organizational Units (OU) you can use to create various groups for resources (computer, users, printers, etc.) on your domain and apply policies/permissions/etc. to them.  You can put files and documents on the server and all your users can share from them based on the permissions you give/assign.

As far as installing software to all 100 computers at once there are various after market tools for this.  Microsoft's is called SCCM (Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager).  I don't have any experience with SCCM but I do know that it is licensed separately (additional to) MS Server.  It's probably not *complicated* but the whole concept of managing systems this way is definitely somewhat advanced and more than anything planning will make or break it.  That means you really need to know all that you don't know, even before you start.

As far as installing and running software on/from the server that is called Terminal Server (TS) services.   This is also licensed on top of Server and has some caveats.  Many software packages will work fine in Terminal Services but some stuff does not.  Do your homework.  Also, on top of cost for the software, this will likely add a pretty large overhead on your server meaning it's now critical for you to size the server accordingly and this will be a substantially more powerful server than if you don't use TS (I mean we're talking about 100 users running apps - I'm assuming at least 50 simultaneous at any given time and perhaps all 100, yes?)  So now add the cost of uprating hardware.

That should get you at least started in the right directions.  I can't stress enough that you have a large hurdle to climb (nothing impossible but your work is definitely cut out for you).  I also can't stress enough the importance of a test bed/lab.  Get 5 or 6 computers, set up server on one of them (you don't need server class hardware to run Server, esp. not for a test bed) and set up the remainder as domain members.  Mimic everything you want to do on this smaller scale.  Test the living snot out of it.  Break it 100 different ways and fix.  Read as much as you can and understand as much as you can before you start on your live environment because if/when things get rough, you don't want 100 users + your bosses complaining and you be clueless what to do.